# Android Studio barcode scanner

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

Any help here would be so appreciated. Tearing what is left of my hair out. I have created a barcode scanner, had 5 filler images built into it so when you scan 5 barcodes these images would present.

Now I want to add more images to it, however when I simply add images into code along with corresponding barcode data, I scan and get a blank screen!

I am a beginner so I may be over looking something silly but as I said I have the scanner working and showing the original 5 images, is it just a case of adding in others?

[image: code example]

Below is the code for what images are shown after which particular barcode has been scanned, the first 5 work fine! Its the last one I've just added that just shows a blank screen, its not the image or the image name etc I've tried all of that.

Updated:::  Code

}

```
private void setImageOfProduct() {
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    String product=getIntent().getStringExtra("productValue");
    if(product.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Jacket")){
        productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.jacket);
    }
    else if(product.trim().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Playstation 4")){
        productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.playstation);

    }else if(product.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Converse")){
        productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.converse);

    }else if(product.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("HP Touchscreen")){
        productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.hptouchscreen);

    }else if(product.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Headphones")){
        productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.headphones);

    }else if (product.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Test")){
        productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.allsaintsshirtcopy);
    }





}
```

Comment: can you debug your application?

Comment: product is already a string, there is no need to call `toString()`

Comment: add an else at the endo of the `else if`  Statements where you add an blank Image or throw an exception if no if is true

Comment: Add your code as text not as image

Comment: Yes it debugs fine says there are no changes to deploy. i created barcode with "Test" as data embedded. I have set the scanner to show particular image after scanner produces the results from scanning "Test" but just blank!!!

Comment: Ok @Jens sorry about that, i will post the code.